# Unabe to Select MSCRM 2011 RiIbbon button from selenium Webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation

I have written selenium code for smoke test on my **MSCRM aplication**. I am unable to click Ribbon Button . Action can be performed by simple click or double click.The Below two Code i have written for Button

```
WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Email Handling']"));
 Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
action2.moveToElement(Email).doubleClick().perform();

OR                 


// driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='incident|NoRelationship|Form|fmc.incident.form.Button.EmailHandling-Medium']/span[2]")).click();
```

Below is HTML structure of page

```
<html webdriver="true">
<head>
<body scroll="no">
<noscript> <div style="padding:10px;background-color:#C9C7BA;"> <span class="warningHeader">Important:</span> <hr size="1" color="#000000"> <span class="warningDescription"> Microsoft Dynamics CRM makes <i>extensive</i> use of your Web browser's client-side abilities. You either have one of these features turned off or your security settings are set so high that they prevent these features from being used. To enable these features, change your browser settings to allow the Microsoft Dynamics CRM site to run JavaScript. <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=245821" style="text-decoration:underline">Learn more</a>. </span> </div> </noscript>
<!--[if MSCRMClient]> <script type="text/javascript"> var MS_CRM_CLIENT_OUTLOOK_INSTALLED=true; </script> <![endif]-->
<span id="crmEventManager"/>
<div id="crmHistoryManager" style="display:none;" count="1"/>
<div id="crmRecentlyViewed"/>
<div id="crmLookupMru"/>
<div id="crmTopBar" class="ms-crm-TopBarContainer ms-crm-TopBarContainerForm" style="visibility: visible; background-position: 719px 0px;">
<div id="crmRibbonManager" currentribbonelement="ribbonContainer0" style="">
<div id="ribbonContainer0" class="loaded" style="display: inline;">
<div id="Mscrm.Ribbon" class="ms-cui-ribbon" unselectable="on" aria-describedby="ribboninstructions" role="toolbar">
<span id="ribboninstruction" class="ms-cui-hidden" unselectable="on">undefined</span>
<div class="ms-cui-ribbonTopBars" unselectable="on">
<div class="ms-cui-tabContainer " unselectable="on">
<ul id="EntityTemplateTab.incident.NoRelationship.Form.Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab" class="ms-cui-tabBody" unselectable="on" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="EntityTemplateTab.incident.NoRelationship.Form.Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab-title">
<li id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Save" class="ms-cui-group" unselectable="on">
<li id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions" class="ms-cui-group" unselectable="on">
<span class="ms-cui-groupContainer" unselectable="on">
<span class="ms-cui-groupBody" unselectable="on">
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge" class="ms-cui-layout" unselectable="on">
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge-0" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge-0-0" class="ms-cui-row" unselectable="on">
<a id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|fmc.incident.form.Button.EmailHandling-Medium" class="ms-cui-ctl-medium " unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" aria-describedby="incident|NoRelationship|Form|fmc.incident.form.Button.EmailHandling_ToolTip" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button">
<span class="ms-cui-ctl-iconContainer" unselectable="on">
<span class="ms-cui-ctl-mediumlabel" unselectable="on">Email Handling</span>
</a>
</span>
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge-0-1" class="ms-cui-row" unselectable="on">
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge-0-2" class="ms-cui-row" unselectable="on">
</span>
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge-1" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">
<span id="incident|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.incident.MainTab.Actions-LargeMediumLarge-2" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">
</span>
```

Can any one look into this Issue. I checked there is no frame on HTML page

I didn't got any exception but there is no action performing after click action on button
after wait of 1 min new window is opening in eclipse IDE and getting **Class File Editor......Source not found**   Issue

Answer (score 0):

I have  just roughly looked at the html element via FireBug I found the top container 
become like that

`<div id="crmHistoryManager" style="display:none;" count="1"/>` eventhough the  div element ends on the same line but the fireFox has different interpretation 
if we run your code,  I get exception which state current element is not visible, hence you can't interact with so the  FireFox has converted the given **div** into a top container for all other **divs** below.

Comment: thanks for loking into it... so how to click on the button. Is there any solution ?

Comment: From you code, you want to click on the link which has the given text  'Email Handling'  the  problem is the top div element is hiding the whole sub elements so if you remove the style="display:none;"  it should work. If you want to see the result of the click, add a listener handler for the  link click to  show a popup message. Can you make changes to the html page?

Comment: thanks for Answer. HTML Code change is not Possible but i will talk with Team and manager
But when i am verfying xpath in firepath it's detecting Exact node which i need

Comment: actuallly, I had a suspicious about the possible change, you need to execute a javascript from selenium to remove the  style attribute before you go further with your code.

Comment: in this case, you need to execute a javascript from selenium to remove the  style attribute before you go further with your code.  I have not tested it but something like that 
`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("
 var path = '//span[text()="Email Handling"]';
document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.removeAttribute('style');");`

Comment: see the  following: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)  and [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)